# Multithreaded TCP server on background thread- how to force close from main thread

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp, server

I have GUI application this application starts server by calling
`start_server()` function. Then there is created TCP passive socket receiving incoming connections in the server loop(we have connection sockets here) and handling them on multiple threads simultaneously.

Now I need some end_server() function that force server and all connections to close. What is the best practice to close such servers.

I consider doing this in such way:

1. pass to `start_server()` function some `server_info_t` structure.
2. then when passive socket is created its descriptor i stored in server_info_t, there is also stored its binding port number
3. in `server_info_t` structure there is `on_server_start` callback that is called asynchronously after server has been created correctly returning some information about created server like port number on which server is listening (this enable to change `GUI controls` like status icon from red to green)
4. then i pass the same structure `server_info_t` info server_loop and there where new connection from client is coming I will take the connection socket and store its descriptor inside server_info_t structure some linked_list_t or hash_map_t of connection sockets.
5. now i can invoke some asynchronous callback like `on_client_connected` and pass handling of connection (connection socket) to another function (separate thread from thread pool), and then server loop waits for next connection. I also need to pass `server_info_t` structure here to remove connection_socket descriptor from **linked_list** of conn socket descriptors it **connection handling** for given client **finish**.
6. Here inside struct server_info there can be another callback function `on_client_disconnected`
7. Now outside this multithreaded server running in the background I have a GUI app that started the server, and it has the pointer to server_info_t structure that stores all information about server: port number, passive socket, linked_list of actually connected connection sockets (active sockets), callback functions pointers that should be called to inform about server events, etc. 
   So I think I could then make `end_server(server_info_t)` (ex. when user clicks **STOP** in **GUI application** user interface) and heres the magic happens... server stops. But how?

**Should I take all connection sockets (while iteration over linked list in server_info_t structure) and close them using (shutdown + close), and then shutdown + close passive socket?**

Then I could even call some callback `on_server_end` which pointer I found in server_info_t structure.

Should I use some mutex to synchronise access to this server_info_t structure?

Comment: Is this about windows? As a first hint, never ever call your own type `something_t`. The `_t` suffix is reserved for the implementation (of your compiler / standard library / ...) in any POSIX environment.

Comment: it's rather unix. I will use this inside my macOS GUI application and also on Windows with cygwin.

Comment: you should probably have some *signal variable* for every *thread* to inform the thread about the shutdown request and then wait for it (e.g. `pthread_join()` with POSIX threads). Maybe you should clarify the platform **and** show some of your code in order to get an actual *answer*

Comment: It is cocoa application in objective-c and I try to write for it server in C that will be cross-platform  (usable also on windows)

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal do you mean this?

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be something as simple as a `volatile sig_atomic_t` as you don't need *exact* synchronization, you only want the thread to eventually know that it should shut down. Of course, the thread shouldn't be stuck in a blocking call. Depending on your design, you could also need to `pthread_cancel()` your threads.

Comment: Ok, it should be something like global variable (flag) indicating whether the server/each connection should close down.

Comment: Shutting down socket descriptors not suffice? I read that when I do shutdown(conn_sock) from other thread it should correctly enforce connection closing ?

Answer (score 1):

**Should I use some mutex to synchronise access to this server_info_t structure?**

You definitely should synchronize access to the shared data structure.

**Should I take all connection sockets (while iteration over linked list in server_info_t structure) and close them using (shutdown + close), and then shutdown + close passive socket?**

This is kind of quick and dirty solution. Better design is to inform worker thread the connection should be closed. In this case you can:

- Inform clients of the server about reason of the connection shutdown
- Complete process of current request

Way to solve "inform" task can be different:

- If you use `select`/`poll`/`epoll` methods you can use designated socket (for ex. `socketpair`) to indicate stop
- If you use blocking calls you can use `pthread_cancel` mechanisms but they are very system-dependent
- If your worker thread wakeups periodically you can use kind of atomic flag